# Exception in thread (Task) is not propagated like example suggests

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, threadpool

The example code from "C# 7.0 in a nutshell", p.580:

```
        Task task = Task.Run(() => { throw null; });
        try
        { 
            task.Wait(); 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
```

executed in my VS2017, does not work the way it is described in the book.
Running from inside the IDE, the `System.NullReferenceException` is immediately thrown (and execution is stopped) at the first line whereas the example suggests that the exception is thrown inside the started thread and is waiting there until someone calls `Wait()` or reads `Result` on the `Task` object. On p.277 the `Task` class is briefly explained and there is a quite unclear mentioning of the *thread pool* which *can* be used. I guess in my case it is not used and instead the main thread is executing the lambda, therefore generating an uncaught exception. I couldn't find a hint on how or where to configure the behaviour of the thread pool or the `Task` class. Or do I miss something entirely different?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nUyWwO (or in VS2017 or VS2019). Are you sure you're not getting confused by the debugger breaking at the point that the exception is thrown?

Comment: Yes, you probably see the debugger highlighting the lambda, which so happens to be on the same line as your `Task.Run`, if you check stacktrace you should probably see task.Wait() in there

Comment: @canton7 you are right, started from outside the IDE, the code behaves as proposed. Hm, that seems to complicate matters when debugging...

Comment: I think it's a bit different GUI, it should be only part of the line highlighted or something to let you differentiate, but stacktrace should always be correct

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik no, I think it is rather the debugger stopping the whole application as soon as one unhandled exception is thrown.

Comment: Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings (or Ctrl + Alt + e), then uncheck "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" (make sure that it's fully unchecked - it's partially checked by default, so you'll have to click it twice)

Comment: @canton7 if you want, you can make it an answer, I'll be happy to accept!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that you are seeing the debugger break at the point that the exception is *thrown*:

[image: Debugger broken on thrown]

The giveaway here is that the dialog says "Exception Thrown", and the `throw` statement is highlighted in yellow.

By default, the debugger will break when any exception inside your code is thrown, regardless of whether it is later caught (or, if you have Just My Code disabled, when any exception anywhere is thrown).

You can change this by clicking the "Open Exception Settings" link in the dialog, or going to Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings, and unchecking "Common Language Runtime Exceptions".

[image: Exception Settings]

You can also control exactly which exceptions the debugger will break on. In the "Exception Thrown" dialog, you can also untick the "Break when this exception type is thrown" checkbox to stop the debugger breaking on that exception type in the future.

When you realise that you want to re-enable breaking on the default set of exceptions, there's a handy reset button at the top of the Exception Settings:

[image: Exception Settings Reset]